# Show that $\mathbf{F}$ is a conservative vector field or not depending on the domain.

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I need to solve this problem for my vector calculus class

> Let $\mathbf{F}=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf{i}+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf{j}$, show that $\mathbf{F}$ is a conservative vector field in $\Omega_{1}=\{-\infty<x<\infty,y>0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, but it is not a conservative vector field in $\Omega_{2}=\{0<x^2+y^2<4\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

**MY ANSWER**

To answer that question, I used the fact that a vector field is conservative if $\text{ }\frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y}=0$.

So I thought I would get something that make the vector field conservative when $y>0$.

But here's what I get: $$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\right)&=&\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\left(\frac{2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)\\ 
&=&\frac{2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\frac{2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
&=&\frac{2(x^2+y^2)-2x^2-2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\\
&=&\frac{2x^2+2y^2-2x^2-2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=0 \end{eqnarray}$$

Therefore, according to what I just found, no matter what the value of $x$ and $y$ is, the vector field will always be conservative. But I am supposed to prove that it is not when $0<x^2+y^2<4$. Where did I make my mistake?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: There is a condition in the theorem for conservative vector fields that the region must be simply connected (no holes).  This is not true for the second region, so the theorem doesn't apply.  Try two paths and see if you get different answers.

Comment: @Michael Burr I don't understand why the second domain is not simply connected. I thought that disks were part of this category.

Comment: It's not a disk, it's missing the center of the disk.

Comment: Calculate the path integral of $\mathbf{F}$ along the unit circle to see that it is not conservative in $\Omega_2$. Observe that the path is not in $\Omega_1$, and, in fact, the field is conservative there because $\Omega_1$ is "star-like" (not sure what is the English term for a domain with every point connected to a fixed point by the line of sight). Of course, that generalizes to simply connected, but that is not always covered on a first course.

Comment: Anyway, your logic is faulty. It is true that for the field to be conservative it must satisfy $\partial F_2/\partial x=\partial F_1/\partial y$, but that is not a *sufficient* condition, only a necessary one. The converse holds only in certain types of domains. Understanding that is precisely what is being tested with this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about this is that the two-dimensional curl that you calculated isn't always $0$. Specifically, $\frac{0}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ is undefined when the denominator is zero. In some sense all of the curl is concentrated at that single point.

It may help to visualize this vector field https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jqa3gpyas4 when analyzing if it's conservative.